# Updating recyclerView after changing the data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a custom recycler Adapter class and I have set the installed apps from device to recyclerView. I have one Uninstall button that when pressed uninstalls the selected apps from recyclerView. My problem is whenever the uninstallation is finished, onActivityResult I've set notifyDatasetChanged method to recyclerAdapter, still the uninstalled apps are there in recyclerView.

```
appList = getInstalledApps();
mAdapter = new CardViewDataAdapter(appList);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

 btnSelection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (int i = 0; i < appList.size(); i++) {
                    AllApps singleApp= appList.get(i);
                    if (singleApp.isSelected() == true) {
                        String app_pkg_name = singleApp.getPackageName();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE);
                        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + app_pkg_name));
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, UNINSTALL_REQUEST_CODE);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

And onActivityResult I've done this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if(resultCode==UNINSTALL_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK ){
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "RecyclerView Updated!!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}
```

Comment: remove that item from list and then call **mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove uninstall app from `appList`, after remove notify your adapter.

`notifyDataSetChanged` will effect your list if there is any change in your list which you have passed to adapter.

Comment: How can I get the removed app position in onActivityResult() to remove it?

Comment: Please maintain the selected positions of uinstalled app and use that position to remove it from app list

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove the UnInstall App in the appList? Like appList.remove(item).
Datas in appList are not changed, so this unInstall App will not disappear.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't remove the item means app which is uninstalled.First you have to remove the item 
from array list and then have to do -

```
notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(0, arraylist.size());
```

here on first line will notify the recycler view that the item of this position is removed and then the second line notify the recycler view about the list item range.

you have to get the clicked item position when user click on any item of recycler view.And then on onActivityResult just remove the item of that position from recyceler view's arraylist.
N.B: you have to make the arraylist and the integer position variable on recycler view adapter to do this. 
}

Comment: can you please elaborate how to get the position of removed app in order to remove it from recyclerview?